# How to make Mojave's quick actions for movies show up in finder?

Tags: mojave, automator, movie

I've two quick actions for movie files in Automator, one of them was a service before the upgrade, the other one is new. Neither of them shows up as quick actions in Finder, and only the older one shows up as a Service in the context menu. What gives?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your desired quick actions are enabled in System Preferences → Extensions → Finder.

[image]

Comment: They don't show up there for me enable them. At least no right away. I've seen them come up later on after a few days (and perhaps a few reboot cycles), though.